# Error in the constructor of gmdistribution

Tags: matlab

I am trying to construct a Gaussian Mixture Model using Matlab's gmdistribution class. The model has dimension `d` and `k` mixtures, with diagonal covariance matrix, for example:

```
mu = rand(k,d);
sigma = rand(1,d,k);
w = rand(1,k);
gmm1 = gmdistribution(mu, sigma, w);
```

The call to the constructor crashes, and it seems that the last parameter (mix proportions), called `p` in the class' constructor, is hidden by another variable. The error happens in my code on two different machines (windows and linux), however it is **not** reproducible with the short snippet of code above. The only clue I've got is the hiding variable which looks like this:

```
p =

        path: '/u/itamark/speech-magneton/source-code/MatlabRecognition/scripts'
           m: {77x1 cell}
         mat: {0x1 cell}
         mex: {0x1 cell}
         mdl: {0x1 cell}
         slx: {0x1 cell}
           p: {0x1 cell}
     classes: {0x1 cell}
    packages: {0x1 cell}
```

I am not using global variables, and anyway `p` is an input variable to the constructor, and not declared global.

**Edit**
Another strange behavior is that if I stop with a breakpoint in the line which calls the `gmdistribution`, and evaluate the line using F9, there is no error. Only if I step using F10 the error happens.

**Edit2** This struct `p` appears [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/what.html), as the output of the builtin function `what`. Needless to say, nowhere in my code I use this function, and even if I did, how could it influence the gmdistribution constructor's workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is really a strange behavior, seems like a bug in Matlab but I am not sure. It turns out the cause is as follows: I have a variable called `what` (I know it's bad coding to hide a builtin function, but I thought about it as a short for 'double-u hat' and I wasn't familiar with `what` as a builtin). I used it in the code like this:

```
some_script; % this script sets the value of the variable "what"
gmm1 = gmdistribution(mu, sigma, what);
```

and Matlab seems to call the builtin function `what` and use its output as the input var to gmdistribution.

The strange thing is, this behavior is not consistent: if you just try something like:

```
what = 1;
fprintf('%d',what)
```

then nothing goes wrong. I will be glad to hear any insights about this issue.